# SSHD applying different PAM rules for localhost connections

Tags: ssh, pam

I am attempting to implement Yubikey auth via SSH. I've edited my /etc/pam.d/sshd file as follows, and it seems to work **while connecting locally** (`ssh user@localhost`):

```
#%PAM-1.0
auth       required pam_yubico.so id=20682 authfile=/etc/yubikey_mappings debug trace
auth       required pam_sepermit.so
auth       substack     password-auth
auth       include      postlogin
account    required     pam_nologin.so
account    include      password-auth
password   include      password-auth
# pam_selinux.so close should be the first session rule
session    required     pam_selinux.so close
session    required     pam_loginuid.so
# pam_selinux.so open should only be followed by sessions to be executed in the user context
session    required     pam_selinux.so open env_params
session    optional     pam_keyinit.so force revoke
session    include      password-auth
session    include      postlogin
```

However, when I try to connect from a remote machine, it does not prompt me for my key. What is the likely issue?

Comment: Are you using ssh key or GSSAPI/krb5 authentication, by any chance? Those authentication methods completely bypass the `auth` stack of PAM.

Comment: @AndrewB Ergh, I am. Now that I'm googling "PAM with SSH key" I'm seeing a hojillion folks with this problem. Hooray for asking the wrong questions. Thanks for the intel.

Answer (score 1):

The general logic is that a PAM enabled program handling shell logins will hit the `auth`, `account`, and `session` stacks in sequence, but a program can simply skip over any of these if it handles one or more of those functions with its own implementations.

`sshd` supports a few modes of authentication that cannot be delegated to PAM, because they rely on methods that do not fall within the scope of password or challenge-response negotiation. These are typically key or ticket based: ssh keys, GSSAPI/krb5, etc.